# One product, multiple options, one global stock entry

Tags: product

My product is tickets which have different age ranges:

Infant 0-2

Child 2-5

Child 5-9

Child 9+

I will have 100 tickets in total but I don’t know in advance how many of each age range I would need so want to be able to set one global quantity of 100.

Is this possible?

Edit:

I have 100 tickets total. The reason I need to have the various age ranges is because children in each range are given a present so I need to know how many of each range are sold. I cannot pre-configure each ticket type with a quantity as its impossible to know how many of each would be required

Answer (score 0):

you can create a 4 different custom options named Infant 0-2, Child 2-5, Child 5-9,Child 9+ and require the customer to fill in the value for each one.
So if he buys 5 tickets he can fill  in `Infant 0 - 2 = 3` and so on.
But you need a verification to see if the sum of all qtys does not go over the toal qty bought.

This is just an idea. I don't have a fully working solution.

Comment: That sounds perfect but the verification I wouldnt have a clue about. I was hoping this was something that would work 'out of the box'. Nothing even in relation to virtual products that would work?